# python SQL database query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

The query below works fine, only instead of refreshing the fixed value of end of last month, I need to pass the variable my_date to the query, so that the code works dynamically. Could someone help?

Here a sample code:

```
import my_db
import pandas as pd
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

my_date = lastMonth.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

my_db =  my_sql_database()
my_query= '''SELECT DISTINCT
            P.ID
            P.VALUE

            FROM P

            WHERE  P.SERIES_DATE = '2019-08-31'
            AND P.PERF_START < Convert(datetime,'2019-08-31')            

            ORDER BY P.ID''' 

my_df = pd.read_sql(my_query, my_db)
```

Comment: Check the docs of the function. `params` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to replace the literal date `'2019-08-31'` in the query with a placeholder token (usually `%s` or `?`, depending on which specific database engine you're using), and then pass in an extra parameter containing the actual value(s) to be substituted for the placeholder(s).

So, your query would end up looking like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
P.ID
P.VALUE
FROM P
WHERE  P.SERIES_DATE = %s
AND P.PERF_START < Convert(datetime, %s)            
ORDER BY P.ID
```

And then as @jpmc26 commented, you would pass in the actual values for the placeholders using the `params` argument:

```
my_df = pd.read_sql(my_query, my_db, params=['2019-08-31', '2019-08-31'])
```